# Frame wont seem to change (opencv, python, raspberry)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, embedded-linux

I would like to capture single frames from web cam each time an event occurs (for example keyboard stroke). What i have done until now is:

```
while(True):
 print "\n\nMain while LOOP\n\n"
 q = raw_input("Take picture? y/n\n")
 if (q == "n"):
  cap.release()
  break
 elif (q == "y"):
  #cap.open(0)
  if(cap.isOpened()):
   start_t = time.clock()
   print "--Trying to capture image..."
   s = False
   frame = None
   try:
    i=0
    while(True):
     s, frame = cap.read()
     i = i + 1
     #cv2.imshow("cam-test", frame)
     cv2.waitKey(1)
     print "Attempts: ", i
     if s: break
    if s:
     print "ok"
   except Exception as inst:
    print "Error occured: ", type(inst)

  #Step 2: process picture
  thresh = image_process(frame, H_low, S_low, V_low, H_max, S_max, V_max, KSIZE)
  print "End of image process, trying to find circles in image now..."


  #Step 3: Find contours
  black_image = np.zeros(thresh.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
  contours = create_contours(thresh, frame) 
  print "length of contours returned: ", len(contours)
  for x in range (0,len(contours)):
   try: 
    cnt = contours[x]
    (x,y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    print "Center: ", center
    print "Radius: ", radius
    cv2.circle(frame, center, radius, (255,0,255),3)
   except Exception as inst:
    print type(inst)
  #test  

  #step 4:
  end_t = time.clock() - start_t
  print "Time of image total image processing and circle search was: ", end_t*1000, " ms"
  #cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
  cv2.imshow("show", frame)
  cv2.waitKey(0) 
  cv2.destroyWindow("video")
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

quit()
```

The problem is that the first frame is ok but the second frame (second "y" hit) is exactly the same as the first one even thouhght i have replaced the image in front of the camera. I have noticed that if i continue to hit "y" for about 5-10 times some time the correct frame is displayed. I was wondering if there is any buffer from the first reading?

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello guys i have noticed that the sixth frame is changing. 
1. Capture single frame
2. .... wait ....
3. Capture second frame (image is the same as the first frame)
4. Capture third frame (image is the same as the first frame)
5. Capture fourth frame (image is the same as the first frame)
6. Capture fifth frame (image is the same as the first frame)
7. Capture sixth frame (this is the new image)

Comment: I have came up with a walk around, replace this line `while(True):
     s, frame = cap.read()` with this 
`while(True):
  s, frame = cap.read()
  s, frame = cap.read()
  s, frame = cap.read()
  s, frame = cap.read()
  s, frame = cap.read()`
But now the problem is that this increase process time which is crucial for me. Does anyone can help me?